# How to increase tap area of a UIButton without changing background image in swift

Tags: xcode, swift, uibutton

Following code worked perfectly except two buttons that close to each other.  Is there any way to work with this extension for buttons that I prefer to use ?  Or, can I exclude buttons that I don't need to use this extension ?

```
extension UIButton {
     public override func hitTest(point: CGPoint, withEvent event: UIEvent?) -> UIView? {
         let buttonSize = self.frame.size
         let widthToAdd = (44-buttonSize.width > 0) ? 44-buttonSize.width : 0
         let heightToAdd = (44-buttonSize.height > 0) ? 44-buttonSize.height : 0
         let largerFrame = CGRect(x: 0-(widthToAdd/2), y: 0-(heightToAdd/2), width: buttonSize.width+widthToAdd, height: buttonSize.height+heightToAdd)
         return (CGRectContainsPoint(largerFrame, point)) ? self : nil
     }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Do not make things complicated, neither the choice of number 44 directly in the code. You don't need to extension UIButton, since you don't need all UIButton behavior in this weird way.

I would just make a larger transparent button (with clear color), then add a small UIImageView as a subview. That's the simplest way I guess.